# What does it by a multivariable function $f(x,y)$ is linear in $x$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

Suppose I have a function $f(x,y)$ that is linear in $x$. I want to know properties of this function.

I guess it inherits some property of a single variable linear function like $f(ax+b,y) = af(x,y)+b$. I specifically wonder what would be a result of $f(x1,y1)-f(x2,y2)$

Comment: You have the right idea, but the first formula should read $f(ax+b,y)=af(x,y)+f(b,y)$. The second expression does not simplify in general.

Comment: Linearity in $x$ means $f(ax_1+bx_2,y) = a f(x_1,y)+bf(x_2,y).$ Your equation is not even a special case of that.